# Creating an overall class diagram with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to generate a Doxygen documentation for my Python project.
It seems like Doxygen does not provide an overall class diagram of the project including Association. It shows only inheritance for a single file.
Is there is a way I can generate an overall class diagram in doxygen?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887733/how-to-obtain-an-overall-uml-class-diagram-of-my-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain an overall UML class diagram of my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887733/how-to-obtain-an-overall-uml-class-diagram-of-my-project)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Is there any other plugin I can use in Doxygen so that I can create such an overall class diagram?

Comment: The [question referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887733/how-to-obtain-an-overall-uml-class-diagram-of-my-project) by @albert has been removed. What was the answer to that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen does not generate class diagrams that contain "association" arrows.
These are the diagram types and my experience with them (stemming from C++):

CLASS_DIAGRAMS: Seems to be an old Doxygen option, superseded by CLASS_GRAPH, which contains more information. CLASS_DIAGRAMS often just show the class without anything else in my output, which is superfluous.

CLASS_GRAPH: This is actually an inheritance diagram, not a full class diagram (internally, it even goes by the name "inherit graph"). It doesn't show a diagram at all if a class is not a derived class or base class.

COLLABORATION_GRAPH: Shows base class, membership and template relations. Doesn't show "inherited by" or "used by" relationships. For a leaf class, the inheritance diagram (CLASS_GRAPH) is just a part of the COLLABORATION_GRAPH.

TEMPLATE_RELATIONS: Shows template relations in a similar style as inheritance, which is helpful for code using template specialization instead of inheritance, e.g. CRTP.

As you have a python project, did you try out Sphinx? sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram comes included with the sphinx-doc distribution but also does not show other types of relations than inheritance.
A web search turned out https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-pyreverse/ which might be what you're looking for. I did not try it out myself.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I will check on pyreverse and see.